# How we can Sending data to server when android application is unistalled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an android app for our driver, But we have a problem when the driver uninstalls the application and the status is online, so the driver is recorded online on the server forever. How do you do that when the driver uninstalls the application, the status changes to offline and sends the status to the server?.

Comment: use croojob on server and check when the appliation is online last time if its more than a day than set offline

Comment: https://clevertap.com/blog/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/